# Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, redis, docker-image

I'm trying to allow communication between my nodeJs docker image with my redis docker image (Mac OS X environment):

nodeJs Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.7.0-slim
EXPOSE 8100
COPY . /nodeExpressDB
CMD ["node", "nodeExpressDB/bin/www"]
```

redis Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.3
EXPOSE 6379
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
```

nodeJs code which is trying to connect to redis is:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
```

docker build steps:

```
docker build -t redis-docker .
docker build -t node-docker .
```

docker run images steps flow:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 redis-docker
docker run -p 8100:8100 node-docker
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1078:14)
```

What should I do inorder to connect to Redis from node-docker?

Comment: run redis with --name redis and connect to redis:6379

Comment: thanks, I tried:  "docker run --name redis-docker -d redis-docker" but getting the same error

Comment: are you able to connect the `redis` from `redis-cli` ?

Comment: yes via redis-cli its working fine

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_redis_service/#create-your-web-application-container

Answer (score 13):

Redis runs in a seperate container which has seperate virtual ethernet adapter and IP address to the container your node application is running in. You need to [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/links) the two containers or create a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/user-defined-networks) for them

```
docker network create redis
docker run -d --net "redis" --name redis redis
docker run -d -p 8100:8100 --net "redis" --name node redis-node
```

Then specify the host `redis` when connecting in node so the redis client attempts to connect to the `redis` container rather than the default of `localhost`

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis')
client.on('connect', () => console.log('Connected to Redis') )
```

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) can help with the definition of multi container setups.

```
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8100:8100"
    networks:
    - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
    - redis
networks:
  redis:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: thanks, I stopped getting error, but now can't see anything in the browser using port 8100, I will check and update

Comment: Sure, I forgot the linking!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'redis-server',
    port: 6379
})
```

Then rebuild ur docker with => **docker-compose up --build**

Answer (score 0):

When connecting in node, use `redis-docker` in the function argument you pass the server IP.

Comment: @OronBen-David instead of 127.0.0.1 connect to redis-docker

Answer (score -1):

if redis installed then run command

`sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Then you will get your site running.

Answer (score -1):

If you can create a new redis docker instance, try mapping the container port to host:

```
docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis

docker container start some-redis
```

Now, you can start the container and connect with host 127.0.0.1

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '6379'
});
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` usually refers to the current container, not a mapped port, and the configuration you show will cause the issue shown in the question.

Answer (score -2):

You can also change your /etc/hosts file to update the dockerip of the redis container.

Find the docker ip by using docker inspect

Answer (score -4):

1. Download the redis server.
2. run the redis server.
3. and then run your project.

It should work just fine. Here's the download link:

[Github - Redis Download Packages](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads)

I hope it works.